# Tikz package labels reflex angle instead of internal angle

Tags: tkz-euclide

I have been trying to draw a geometrical diagram using the tikz package and just started using it. Somehow, the reflex angle is labelled instead of the interior angle but I want the interior angle BAC labelled. Could anyone please help? Here is my code (shortened version):

```
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\tkzDefPoint[label=below left:{$A$}](-2,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint[label=below:{$O$}](0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint[label=below right:{$C$}](2,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint[label=below:{$D$}](4,0){D}
\tkzDefPoint[label=above:{$B$}](0.486, 1.94){B}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,D A,B B,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=-1.2](B,A,C){$38^\circ$}
\tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=5mm](B,A,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `C,A,B`? Then you probably don't need to use a negative `pos` either.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you so much for your help! I forgot to test that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with `angles` library of TikZ, the order of the points matter.
Instead of `C,A,B` you can use `B,A,C` here and the arc will be drawn correctly.
The same applies for the label where you can now use a positive `pos`.

I've changed the definition of *B* to be in polar coordinates. This might be more preferrable than calculating some odd numbers yourself.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=2];
\tkzDefPoint[label=below left :{$A$}](-2,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint[label=below      :{$O$}]( 0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint[label=below right:{$C$}]( 2,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint[label=below      :{$D$}]( 4,0){D}
\tkzDefPoint[label=above      :{$B$}](76:2){B}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,D A,B B,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.2       ](C,A,B){$38^\circ$}
\tkzMarkAngle [arc=l,size=5mm](C,A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]